# after setting the input field value to a state object with an empty value, now I can't type anything in the input field in the UI. i am using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am building a form to take data from a user then save them in a state in order to post it to an endpoint later, so I saved the values of the input to an empty string and I will validate the inputs later but once I set the value to formValues elements and I open the browser to test my code , however how much I try to type anything in the input field, nothing is written.
and in the console I appears that I take only one letter.

here is my code

```
import react, { Component, useState } from 'react';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEyeSlash, faEye } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import './sign.css';

const Sign = () => {

    const intialValues = { firstname: "", lastname: "", mobile: "", email: "", password: "", cpassword: "" }

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(intialValues);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = (err) => {
        err.preventDefault();

    }



    return (

        <div className='signup'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <div className="name">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="First name"
                                name="First name"
                                value={formValues.firstname}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Last name"
                                name="Last name"
                                value={formValues.lastname}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Business mobile number"
                            name="Business mobile number"
                            value={formValues.mobile}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required />
                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Email Adress"
                            name="Email Adress"
                            value={formValues.email}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required />
                        <br />
                        <div className="password">
                            <input
                                type='password'
                                placeholder="Password"
                                name="psw"
                                id='password'
                                value={formValues.password}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} id='togglePassword' />
                            <br />
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                name="Confirm Password"
                                id='Cpassword'
                                value={formValues.cpassword}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                required />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} id='togglePassword' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" className="check" />i’ve read and agree with <a href="url" >Terms of service</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="clearfix">
                        <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}




export default Sign;
```

Comment: the problem was that the name attribute of the input is not the same as the name that refers to it in the intialValues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleSubmit` method, you are expecting the `input` element's name to be same as one of the `initialValues` object keys. But the `input` tag in your JSX does not specify correct value of the `name` attribute because of which the binding does not happen.

For each of your `input` tags in your JSX, change their `name` attribute to match the corresponding key of state object. For eg

```
  <input
     type="text"
     placeholder="First name"
     name="firstname"
     value={formValues.firstname}
     onChange={handleChange}
     required />
```

Answer (score 0):

the names of the input fields are not the same as the names of the states (object keys) you have taken at the top, please change it like this,

```
import react, { Component, useState } from 'react';
```

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEyeSlash, faEye } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import './sign.css';

const Sign = () => {

```
const intialValues = { firstname: "", lastname: "", mobile: "", email: "", password: "", cpassword: "" }

const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(intialValues);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
}

const handleSubmit = (err) => {
    err.preventDefault();

}



return (

    <div className='signup'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                <div className="name">
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="First name"
                            name="firstname"
                            value={formValues.firstname}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Last name"
                            name="lastname"
                            value={formValues.lastname}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Business mobile number"
                        name="mobile"
                        value={formValues.mobile}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        required />
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Email Adress"
                        name="email"
                        value={formValues.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        required />
                    <br />
                    <div className="password">
                        <input
                            type='password'
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            id='password'
                            value={formValues.password}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required />
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} id='togglePassword' />
                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Confirm Password"
                            name="cpassword"
                            id='Cpassword'
                            value={formValues.cpassword}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            required />
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} id='togglePassword' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" className="check" />i’ve read and agree with <a href="url" >Terms of service</a>
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix">
                    <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

}